# Laravel 7 - weird timestamp migration behavior

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm creating a table via a migration file.

I have multiple timestamp columns which one of is not supposed to be nullable.

If i set that one column first in order the migration goes through just fine, if I place any nullable timestamp column before it, the migration fails with an exception:

`` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'credit_date' (SQL: create table `feedback_survey_records` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` bigint unsigned not null, `feedback_survey_id` bigint unsigned not null, `reward` smallint not null, `credit_status` varchar(45) null, `answer_date` timestamp null, `open_date` timestamp null, `credit_date` timestamp not null, `decline_date` timestamp null, `decline_reason` varchar(255) null, `response_id` varchar(255) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' engine = innodb) ``

**Successful migration**

```
            $table->timestamp('credit_date');
            $table->timestamp('answer_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('open_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('decline_date')->nullable();
```

**Failing migration**

```
            $table->timestamp('answer_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('open_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('credit_date');
            $table->timestamp('decline_date')->nullable();
```

I looked at the database and noticed that laravel automatically added a default value and extra instructions on the successful migration
[Database structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHhfe.png)

Can someone please shed some light on why this might be happening?

Comment: Not sure here, but the query looks perfectly fine. What database are you using? And which version?

Comment: Compare that *errorous* query with successful one.

Comment: @killstreet I'm using MySQL 5.7